# Using explode with setcookie to set one cookie with multiple name and values

Tags: php, cookies

I really not getting how to do this

From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> Cookies names can be set as array names and will be available to your
>   PHP scripts as arrays but separate cookies are stored on the user's
>   system.

This is okay to me and I got and could use like below

```
setcookie("cookie[three]", "cookiethree");
setcookie("cookie[two]", "cookietwo");
```

But this method will create multiple cookies and that is I don't want

PHP manual also says

> Consider explode() to set one cookie with multiple names and
>   values.

But I did not get how to use explode to set one cookie with multiple names and values?

Please someone explain this.

But not getting this

Comment: Answer about `explode`: [on wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/cookies#Retrieving_cookie_data)

Comment: So you just store arrays(or else) in one cookie as string, but with multidimensional array in it with many values. Thats how it described in manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are nothing else than a dumb key/value storage system. It's as simple as that.

It happens that PHP offers a nifty feature on top of that: cookies whose names contain square brackets in the described format will be combined into a single array variable when reading cookies back from PHP. But that's the only exception, it doesn't affect the way cookies work and, as you've said, it's a feature you don't need.

Said that, you only need to think of the cookie value as a whiteboard where you can put anything you want, as long as it's text. And there're many PHP functions that allow you to convert exotic stuff like arrays into plain text:

- [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize)
- [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode)
- [implode()](http://php.net/implode)
- ...

Use your imagination and you're done ;-)

**Update:** A little remark—I've mentioned `serialize()` for completeness, but it's probably not worth the effort since it'd be very complicate to ensure you don't open the door to code injection.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a cookie like this:

```
setcookie("cookiename", "value1;value2;value3;value4");
```

and then use explode like so:

```
$a = explode(';', $_COOKIE['cookiename']);
```

Then you will get an array of values from a single cookie.

It is also saying you should not do this... in the following sentence of the doc.

```
setcookie("cookiename", serialize( array("value1", "value2", "value3") );
// next request
$a = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookiename']);
```

because that is unsafe as users can modify their cookies to non-array values.

Answer (score -1):

Use Serialize and Unserialize

Ex :

```
$ckArr= array();
        $ckArr['abc'] = "abc";
        $ckArr['xyz'] = "xyz";
        $ckArr['pqr'] = "pqr";

        $ckStr= serialize($ckArr);
        setcookie("mycookie", $ckStr, $time, $servername);
```

And you can unserialised it using :

```
$cookieContent = unserialize($_COOKIE['mycookie']);

print_r($cookieContent);
```

Comment: This is specifically discouraged for security issues on php.net. See my answer.